# SSL with Oracle thin driver - what would be the JDBC URL for creating a connection?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, driver, thin

We are trying to connect to Oracle using Oracle thin driver with SSL.

We are able to connect to Oracle using thin driver using following connect string to connect without SSL - `jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:<port>:<service_name>`.

Can anyone help with the connect string if we want to use **SSL encryption**?

What would be the parameters to be given in JDBC URL to make a connection?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/clntsec.htm#JJDBC28339

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you add to the connect string is `PROTOCOL=tcps` - everything else  gets set up through JSSE properties. You'll have different choices depending on whether you just want to use SSL for encryption, or whether you also want it for authentication (and if so, whether you prefer Oracle Wallets or Java Keystores).

I feel like the official [SSL with Oracle JDBC Driver whitepaper](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf) is a great walkthrough ([this post](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/activate-ssl-oracle-jdbc-thin-driver/) is basically a non-pdf version of the same info). You might also find [this Oracle blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc%2C-tlsv12%2C-jks-or-oracle-wallets) helpful.

There's several questions on here about this topic, they have some good code examples that might be helpful: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210109/jdbc-connect-to-oracle-database-with-ssl) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583305/connecting-to-ssl-enabled-oracle-db-through-java-jdbc) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53748245/creating-an-ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-with-java) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41281973/java-jdbc-unable-to-connect-to-a-oracle-database-with-ssl)